# Allow to display only certain months to select in orbeon form's datepicker

Tags: orbeon

Is it possible to allow the datepicker to only display certain months for user selection in orbeon form? e.g. only display Jan - Aug 2020?  Or, is it possible to disable all dates out of those months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude specific days (dates), so those days become greyed out in the date picker, and the value is also invalid if somehow one of those days gets selected. This is convenient to, say, exclude holidays. But it seems that supporting a start/end date is what you're looking for. This isn't yet implemented, see request for enhancement [#4557](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4557).

So, for now, you can only enforce this through a formula (in Control Settings → Validations and Alerts). Users will still be able to select the date, i.e. it won't be greyed out in the date picker, but they will immediately see a message telling them that the date is invalid.

Comment: I have also added a +1 from you on [#4557](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4557). ‑Alex